# Custom checkbox with label not fitting

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have tried to build my own checkbox which look like a buttom  and find various solution but the design is still not good because the one of the element is not properly showing

As you can see on the image below, once the image is selected, the oragne background is not covering the entire button to looks good.

[image]

I try to fix it but most of the time, I am breaking the design

```
import React from 'react';
import './CheckboxButton.css';

class CheckboxButton extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div id="ck-button">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" hidden/><span>{this.props.text}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default CheckboxButton;
```

the css is :

```
 
 #ck-button {
     margin:3px;
     background-color: transparent;
     overflow:auto;
     float:left;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
     border-radius: 21px;
     border: solid 2px #ff7255;

 }
 
 #ck-button label {
     float:left;
     width: fit-content;
     padding: 1px 10px 0px 10px;
     font-family:Source Sans Pro;
     font-size: 18px;

 }
 
 #ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
     padding:0px 0px;
     display:block;
     color: #ff7255;
 }
 
 #ck-button label input {
     position:absolute;
     top:-20px;
 }
 
 #ck-button input:checked + span {
     background-color:#ff7255;
     color:#fff;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Any idea how to make the full button in orange?

Comment: Change `background-color: transparent;` to anything but `transparent`?

Comment: If you want to have your button's background orange why did you set `transparent` background in your button? You can with a bit of javascript switch the color of the button on click, even with `:hover` or `:active`in the css should be able to do the trick I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule of thumb, when creating a custom checkbox always apply the styles on the clickable element. (in your case `span`)

```css
#ck-button {
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#ck-button span {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  border-radius: 21px;
  border: solid 2px #ff7255;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ff7255;
  user-select: none;
}

#ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked+span {
  background-color: #ff7255;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label id="ck-button">
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" hidden/>        <span>text</span>
  </label>
```